# Creating a C++ makefile for an expected .o file?

Tags: c++, makefile

I have two files, `main.cpp` and `sub.h`.

`sub.h` contains just this one line

```
int sub(int n, int *A, int *B, int *C);
```

and `main.cpp` is a very basic program where we take in user input for three `int*`s, `A, B, C`, and then call the `int sub(int n, int *A, int *B, int *C)` function. However, the implementation of `int sub(int n, int *A, int *B, int *C)` is in another file that I do not have access to: `sub.o`.

How would I write this Makefile? I am new when it comes to making Makefiles and it confuses me on how I should structure this code, especially with `sub.o`. I am confused on what my dependencies are and how I should even begin to write it.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "don't have access to" `sub.o`.  Does that mean you don't have either the source file or the object file?  Without at least one of those you can't create the program at all, so how to write a makefile is moot.

Comment: @MadScientist when I submit my code, the person who will compile the code will have access to it.

Comment: Well, without access to that file you won't be able to build `main`; it will always fail.  So, having a makefile doesn't seem so useful to me.  YMMV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just include `sub.o` as a dependency of another target. No need to write a recipe for it.
For the `main` target you may do something like:

```
main: main.o sub.o
  g++ -o $@ $^
```

This makes use of the built-in default rules that know how to compile main.cpp into main.o.

If the file ever goes missing, Make will come complain that it doesn't know how to create it:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `sub.o'.  Stop.
```